# updating byte count on label through ProgressEvent

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex3, flexbuilder

I have main.mxml and an external class com.audio.AudioPlayer.as

AudioPlayer loads an audio file and has an event for counting bytesLoaded and bytesTotal.

I would like to push the bytesLoaded information continuously as its being loaded into a label on main.mxml from the ProgressEvent.PROGRESS

```
snd.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, listenProgress);


    private function listenProgress(event:ProgressEvent):void
    {
        progressID.text = event.bytesLoaded + " / " + event.bytesTotal;
    }
```

I can't find a way to target the label control in main.mxml, from inside AudioPlayer and to continuously update the byte count.

Any help, much appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I figured out a work around. In AudioPlayer.as I declared:

```
public var snd:Sound = new Sound();
```

in main.mxml I added the event listeners for snd:

```
newAudio.snd.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundComplete);
newAudio.snd.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, listenProgress);
```

... in doing so I can update my mxml control by declaring:

```
[Bindable] private var progUpdate:String;

<mx:Label text="{progUpdate}" x="254.75" y="46" width="506.5" />
```

so basically I just moved the eventListeners from the AudioPlayer class and into the document class.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bindable variable in AudioPlayer and set it to the correct value in your event handler.

In your mxml, bind the label's text to that value.

Comment: Hi Marc, so I've tried what you said. I did:

AudioPlayer.as

    [Bindable]
    public var progUpdate:String; 
    progUpdate = event.bytesLoaded + " / " + event.bytesTotal;


Main.mxml

private var newAudio:AudioPlayer = new AudioPlayer();    
progressID.text = newAudio.progUpdate;

The text field doesn't update at all unfortunately. Could I have missed something?